# AppCache and pushState

Tags: html, pushstate, html5-appcache

For my mobile application I want to use pushState and AppCache, but this seems to be tricky.

To make pushState work, my web server redirects every url (except assets like the manifest file itself, images, css- and js files) to `/index.html` internally.

E.g. a request to `/articles/123` will redirect to `/` respectively `/index.html` (so the originally requested URL is still visible in the browser).

This causes the request to the `manifest.appcache` to a wrong path, like `/articles/123/manifest.appcache` instead of `/manifest.appcache`, which leads us to the problem that the browser creates a new cache group for every directly accessed URL (e.g. by a Google search)

I redirect `(.*)/manifest\\.appcache` to `/manifest.appcache` and it is interpreted, so that should work as expected. I think the main issue is that the browser treats the `manifest.appcache` file on URL level instead of domain level.

So this leads me to the following questions:

1. Is this a practicable approach?
2. If yes, can I tell the browser to use the AppCache on domain level and how?
3. If no, what am I not thinking through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put the `manifest` attribute on the `<HTML>` element just set the path properly to point to the root directory:

```
<html manifest="/appcache.manifest">
```

Comment: That holy slash... Thanks!